# Conditional Select in View - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, select, view, case

I have a view that needs to show the converted price of items.
I have 2 tables to join from **Item_Price** & **FX_Rate**

Simplified example:

**Item table with millions of data**

| IP.ITEM | Item_Price.PRICE | Item_Price.CURRENCY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | USD |
| Orange | 77 | INR |
| Avocado | 22 | MXN |
| Pear | 0.9 | USD_OLD |

**FX Rate table which is consistently updated with real-time rate**

| FX_Rate.CURRENCY | FX_Rate.FX |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1 |
| INR | 0.013 |
| MXN | 0.049 |
| USD_OLD | 1.79 |

Both table structures can't be modified, so I'm creating a view to display the standardized price of items with :

```
CREATE VIEW USD_ITEMS AS
  SELECT 
    IP.NAME AS NAME,
    (Item_Price.PRICE * FX_Rate.FX) AS USD_price
    ...
    FROM 
      Item_Price IP
      JOIN FX_Rate FX ON( 
        IP.CURRENCY = FX.CURRENCY
      )
```

While everything shall follow,
**USD_OLD is now outdated and all items with USD_OLD as currency need to be converted with USD's fx rate instead**

I tried to use *IF / CASE WHEN* but I can't find a way to purposely switch the FX where CURRENCY='USD_OLD'

Error Pseudocode? :

```
CASE USD_price 
  WHEN FX_Rate.CURRENCY='USD_OLD' 
    THEN (Item_Price.PRICE * FX_Rate.FX WHERE FX_Rate.CURRENCY='USD_OLD')   
  ELSE (Item_Price.PRICE * FX_Rate.FX)
```

I know the above is not possible as the view is `JOIN ON Item_Price.CURRENCY = FX_Rate.CURRENCY`

Will a temporary table in the view help?

I can't work my head around this and really need some expert help, thank you.

Comment: instead of a view use a function that calculates the orice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW USD_ITEMS AS
  SELECT 
    IP.NAME AS NAME,
    (Item_Price.PRICE * FX_Rate.FX) AS USD_price
    ...
    FROM 
      Item_Price IP
      JOIN FX_Rate FX ON( 
        IF(IP.CURRENCY = 'USD_OLD' , 'USD', IP.CURRENCY)  = FX.CURRENCY
      )
```

Comment: To me, this solution is cleaner and works directly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to join the `USD` row all the time and then use it only when necessary. For example:

```
create view usd_items as
select
  ip.name,
  ip.price * case when ip.currency <> 'USD_OLD' then fx.fx else u.fx end
  as usd_price
from item_price ip
join fx_rate fx on ip.currency = fx.currency
cross join (
  select * from fx_rate where currency = 'USD'
) u
```